# Rails. jQuery form submit on field blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

In my app there's an order model with has_many order_items.

Order page:

```
<div id="cart-rows">
    <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
    <%= render 'orders/cart_row', product: order_item.product, order_item: order_item %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

cart_row partial (each for one order_item):

```
<div class="cart-row col-xs-12" id="order-item-<%= order_item.id %>">
<h3><%= product.name %></h3>

<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-9 cart-form-wrapper">

    <%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_field :color_quantity, value: order_item.color_quantity.to_i,
                                                                        min: 0, class: "form-control cart-quantity" %>

        <h4>
            &nbsp;x&nbsp;<%= order_item.var_price("color") %>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ruble'></i>
        </h4>

        <% if order_item.color_quantity > 0 %>
            <h4>
                &nbsp;= <%= order_item.color_quantity * order_item.var_price("color") %>
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ruble'></i>
            </h4>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>

        <%= f.submit "", class: "btn-hidden submit-cart-row" %>

        <h4>
            Total: <%= order_item.item_total %>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ruble'></i>
        </h4>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

In each row there's a form with each product types and quantity of it.
When form submits, information (each type total price and its quantity) in this current cart_row recalculates with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cart-quantity').blur(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

I want to submit it each time on field blur.
The problem is that it works but only for the first blur. When I change another field and blur it nothing happens. Otherwise if I hit enter forms update normally.
I don't see any errors in the console. Server log is empty because nothing happens: on blur action doesn't fire. It must be some javascript error but I cannot trace it.

Order items controller:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_order
    before_action :set_order_item, only: [:update, :destroy]

  def create
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

  def update
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items

  end

  def destroy
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

    private

    def set_order
        @order = current_order
    end

    def set_order_item
        @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_item_params 
        params.require(:order_item).permit(:color_quantity, :high_quantity, :spec_quantity, :product_id)
    end

end
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is sent back from the server after the first `submit()`? Does the form get changed from that response?

Comment: Thank you for response Mike, I found what was causing the error.
I was using sloppy method to update cart partial, something like
`$(".shopping-cart").load(document.URL + ' .shopping-cart');`
So this was a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing the error.
I was using a sloppy method to update cart partial, something like
`$(".shopping-cart").load(document.URL + ' .shopping-cart');`
So this was a reason.